# StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, core-api

i'm building a Web Application to consume A REST FULL API ASP.Net Core Web Service, i have Problem when i update a records.
i'm trying to Call Put Method from API ASP.Net core by ASP.Net Core application

I have got an NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmployee(int id)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    using(var httpClient=new HttpClient())
    {
        using(var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("myURI/employee/" + id))
        {
             string apiResponse = await 
             response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

             employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>apiResponse);
        }
    }
    return View(employee);                   
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    Employee receivedemployee = new Employee();
    using(var httpClient=new HttpClient())
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

       content.Add(new             
        StringContent(employee.EmployeeId.ToString(),Encoding.UTF8, 
            "application/json"), "id");
            content.Add(new 
        StringContent(employee.FirstName,Encoding.UTF8, 
          "application/json"),"FirstName");
            content.Add(new StringContent(employee.LastName, 
         Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "LastName");
            content.Add(new StringContent(employee.DateOfBirth.ToString(), 
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "Email");
            content.Add(new StringContent(employee.PhoneNumber, 
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "DateOfBirth");
            content.Add(new StringContent(employee.Email, Encoding.UTF8, 
           "application/json"), "Email");

            using (var response = await httpClient.PutAsync("myURI/api/employee", content))
            {

                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ViewBag.Result = "Success";
                receivedemployee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(apiResponse);
            }
            return View(receivedemployee);
        }
     }
}
```

i expected updating a record

Comment: what line are you getting the error?

Comment: i also don't think you need to be using the response... im going to try and clean up your code a bit and put it in the answer

Comment: i have got an Error in the view.

Comment: every thing working well, but only thing when i update record i get an error , the response variable value when i pause the the Debug is ={StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, etc

Comment: `myURI/employee/{id}` this route.. can i see the method for that api endpoint?

Comment: try changing your HttpPost attribute to HttpPut.

Comment: ok i will try Right now

Comment: also i dont think you need two methods to do this... maybe combine them as well... let's see give me a second ok

Comment: i have changed the Attribut [HttpPost] to [HttpPut] for the UpdateEmployee Method and did not work, the Method with the [HttpPut] did not got debugged from the compiler

Comment: the First UpdateEmployee Method for getting  the data and show it on the View and the Second UpdateEmployee Method with Attibute [HttpPost] to update the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit. try it this way

I removed unnecessary using blocks and serialized your employee class with a single "application/json" encoding.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmployee(int id)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
      (HttpMethod.Get, $"myURI/employee/{id}");

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(apiResponse);

    return View(employee);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    Employee receivedEmployee = new Employee();

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, $"myURI/employee/{employee.EmployeeId}")
    {
         Content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(employee), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };

     var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

     string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     ViewBag.Result = "Success";
     receivedEmployee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(apiResponse);

     return View(receivedEmployee);
 }
```

Comment: sorry I misspelled JavaScriptSerializer... i fixed it.. capital S for Script

Comment: please keep in mind, we might have to change my code from `var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"myURI/employee/{id}")` to `var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, $"myURI/employee/{id}")`

Comment: i have got the same Error. i have tried with both Methods (post and put).NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Views_Home_UpdateEmployee.ExecuteAsync() in UpdateEmployee.cshtml
+
            <td>@Model.EmployeeId</td>

Comment: the id in the second Method made issue .  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, $"https://webapicodefirst20190620092631.azurewebsites.net/api/employee/{id}") //<---
Error CS0103 The name 'id' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. So in the parameters next to employee, put int id. So it will look like (Employee employee, int id). And don’t forget to put a slash in the route /employee/{id}

Comment: i just updated my answer... so we're going to grab the `id` from the `employee` object being passed in with `employee.Id`, and we're going to assign that to `id` and we're going to use that `id` to update the correct employee

Comment: Everything working now, jPhizzle, thank you very much

Comment: this is the  that was casing the problem -var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, $"https://webapdefirst2019031.azurewebsites.net/api/employee/{employee.EmployeeId}") i must add the employee id to update the record.

Comment: Great to hear! If it works can you do me a favor and mark my answer as correct? :)

Comment: i have just right now marked your Answer as correct, but how favor the Answer?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: yeah, what's up?